# why do I resort to the zero vector i.e homogeneous equation to find weather a set of vectors are linearly dependent or not?

Tags: linear-algebra, independence

in a linearly dependent system there is more than one way to reach a point and to test this I resort to the zero vector.
is it because of simplicity since I know a sure way to reach it(the trivial solution) and any other new way if existent would be a new one?

if that's the case, would I be able to test for linear dependence for a vector other than the zero vector and how?

Comment: A trivial combination gives always the zero vector: but a non-zero vector doesn't need to be a linear combination of your vectors.

Answer (score 1):

Actually, the definition of linear independence of vectors $v_1,\ldots, v_n$ is exactly
$$a_1 \cdot v_1 + \ldots + a_n \cdot v_n = 0 \Rightarrow a_1 = \ldots = a_n = 0.$$

The answer to both of your questions is basically YES. You could also take another point which lies in the linear span of your system, find a way to reach it and prove that this is the only way to reach this point. Hence, proving linear (in)dependence this way requires two steps:

1. Find way to reach some vector $v^*$
2. Test whether there is another way to $v^*$

However, as you stated, for the zero vector, we already know a way making the first step obsolete.